# Can I soak and rejuice the pulp that comes out of a juicer?

Tags: juice

If I'm juicing Oranges it takes quite a few oranges to get a decent amount of juice. Would it be possible to soak the pulp in water and send it through the juicer again? If so, what is the best way to go about that? What ratio of water to pulp would be optimal?

Answer (score 1):

The water soluble parts of the orange are all already solved in its juice. So in mixing the pulp with water, you aren't leeching any new orange components. The result won't be orange juice by any stretch, just water which has washed the last drops of juice your juicer didn't get.

If you drink your juice diluted (I prefer it that way: less sweet, less fructose, better value), doing it might provide it with a better diluting liquid than pure water. But it won't be anywhere near real orange juice for drinking on its own.

If you want to get some more orange taste out of the pulp, you can try boiling the pulp, or using a different solvent like alcohol or a fat. All will produce something very different from true orange juice (a syrup for the first if you add sugar, liqueur with alcohol or an essential oil with fat), and the amount will be rather small. So probably not worth the work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that the resulting juice would be bitter from the orange plup and not sweet like the first juice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely confident, but it strikes me as sure, you could add water to the pulp, and then you could squeeze water right back out of it. It'd have a very slight orange flavor.

If you want to get more orange flavor out of your oranges, zest them before juicing and then use the zest.

Answer (score 0):

Turning your question around, we've found that with our twin-gear masticating juicer ([an older version of this)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Y1A0BO), we usually run the pulp through it a second time.  It comes out pretty moist the first time, but the second time it's pretty much squeezed dry.